# How to get Chartered Engineer in the UK? Should I pay some fees (every year) to keep this title?

Tags: phd, career-path, computer-science, titles, professional-association

I have completed PhD in Computing in UK. Can I apply for a CEng title as I have a Computing degree (not exactly engineering)?

If I get one, should I pay some subscriptions (every year/month) to keep this title?

What are the advantages of having CEng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CEng qualification (it is post-nominal) is awarded on the accreditation of the engineering experience and qualification achieved. The full specification of the necessary standard is shown in the document entitled [*The UK Standard for Professional Engineering Competence (UK-SPEC)*](http://www.engc.org.uk/standards-guidance/standards/uk-spec/). Although CEng is not a title it does enable you to work towards the Engineering title of [EurIng](http://www.feani.org/site/index.php?id=111) (pre-nominal) which is awarded by [FEANI](http://www.feani.org/site/index.php).

In Academia in the UK it would be expected that researchers and Academics in engineering (STEM) hold both professional and academic qualifications and titles as they are part of the education path for professional practicing engineers. Thus only possessing a PhD would make you a less qualified than other applicants or colleagues. For career development it is useful to have a full set of qualifications, including membership of the relevant professional bodies.

A BSc and MSc (in an accredited degree subject) would normally be considered the academic level necessary for the CEng topped up with an appropriate amount of relevant professional practice. If the PhD contained an appropriate amount of project management and technical engineering content it could satisfy the professional component of the CEng, but not always. Sometimes a period of employment might be needed to top-up.

A fee is payable for the application to cover the accreditation of your qualification and experience and then an annual membership fee thereafter. If you stop paying the membership fee you are not considered an active professional and therefore the qualification/title lapses. If you use the qualification/title without paying professional fees then this is considered an act of unprofessionalism.

I have a set of such qualifications in computing and use the letters:

> Eur Ing MBCS CITP CEng

in formal academic contexts. It is useful in explaining to students about the paths to qualification and professional practice in our subject. It also shows that the person teaching them is fully qualified to do so, and knows the material from professional practice and not just from books.